# I'm having an error in android studio about build failure

Tags: android

> Error:(21, 76) error: cannot find symbol variable fab
>   Error:Execution failed for task `enter code here :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

this is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please you the edit link to update your question instead of the comments

Comment: Also, this code you have show is not the problem. `cannot find symbol variable fab` means you have used the variable `fab` somewhere where it cannot be accessed. Please show the entire Activity.

Comment: There u go buddy help me out ..

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code... This is your only Activity? You are using Android Studio? It should point you at any invalid variables with a red-line under the variable name. If there are none of those, then you shouldn't be getting a compile error

Comment: Please build with gradlew on the command line and pass the --debug flag.  Then share the results here.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone but i know what the problem was: `Floatingactionbutton` should not be written there as I deleted it in design mod in activity_main.xml